# Capacitors when to not use on linear voltage

Tags: capacitor

So capacitors help alot to smooth everything.I need that.

Is there a way capacitors harm a circuit if you need a smooth clean voltage?

What happens if i have 5v powersupply and i put lots of various capacitors(ceramic,electrolytic,tantalum), all rated over 5v btw. ground and +5v?

Do i get a smooth stable clean signal or do i harm my circuit in some way?

**Have capacitors no drawback appart from low ESR / charging discharging time?**

---

**EDIT**

I'm new to electronics 2 months ago i didn't even know what caps are for .
Even if i replaced various caps on older electronic devices.

Now after reading some stuff about electronics i understood that caps are good.

Those "Batteries" that store energy & "linearize" the voltage output. All i needed to know is if there is a drawback.

I experiment atm with simple circuits , simple ic's and most examples on the web are capacitor less. Even if each IC's Vcc should have a CAP. Each button each pot each sensor.To linearize the voltage and protect from current rushes.

All i wanted to know was if there was some sort of drawback on those "simple" circuits.

Apparentely no. If you don't exceed the capacitance.

My question started with totally different words wich i deleted after

> "The wall of text makes it less likely that people will answer your
>   question"

Like i said i'm not an electronical engineer so many things aren't that logical for me, I also have no oscilloscope to check the correct value of the capacitors by myself. All i can do is to google and find an adeguate formula and base everything on that.

Said that i don't get all the downvotes.

I'm just trying to learn new stuff and compensate the missing measuring tools with the knowledge i get from my friend google and you guys.

Actually a simple answer like "yes more caps don't harm" would have ben enough.

Comment: This is basically an electronics degree course, not a question.

Comment: i'm happy with basic tips ,in detail about clean 3.3v,5v,12v signal at the powersource side and the relative circuits.

Comment: Can you simplify your question so you're asking a single question, such as "how do you decide what size decoupling capacitor to use"? You may find your individual questions have already been answered here, if you phrase them like that.

Comment: i'm planning to power of various MCU's from one powersource using boost converters and other efficent switching power adapters.. the point is that the drawback on those is the noise.

Comment: cocco the switching noise of the converters is basically unavoidable. You just need to design around those issues, putting sensitive ADC stuff as far away as possible, using many different capacitors, and if possible feeding the ADC with an ultra low noise linear regulator which the switching converter as the input. This question you have posed here is too broad

Comment: the question can lead to a really complex answer... with basic tips on how to put them , where to put them, which type , what size and more. But if there is a basic rule that the above logic isn't totally wrong , on how i choose to put capacitors, then a simple "yes, it does not harm to put capacitors in lines where smooth voltage is needed." or "No caps! create more noise or explode or whatever" would be enough.

Comment: ok changing the title.

Comment: What is your specific question? If we all give you some tips, how will you choose which is the best answer?

Comment: "Is there a way capacitors harm a circuit if you need a smooth clean voltage?" this one

Comment: i would chose the one that gives the best answer.the most important.but to get actually more than one answer here in electronics stack you must be very lucky. So your answer?

Comment: cocco it is more likely than not, to get greater than one user-submitted answer for any particular question here.

Comment: the comments and the nice answer from @Robert Stiffler make me think of this "its better to put random sized capacitor btw every vcc&gnd than putting none". Are there really NO drawbacks (appart from low esr mentioned). the charging time / discharging time is actually a benefit on most circuits. So... if in doubt "put another cap!"

Comment: What to say... if this is true i really like the capacitors even more now. No One contradicts this?

Comment: If the "old question" stuff is no longer needed to explain what you want answered, please delete it. The wall of text makes it less likely that people will answer your question.

Comment: -1 and vote to close for incoherent wall of text. [This](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/194039/are-too-high-capacitance-capacitors-bad-for-the-circuit) might answer [some](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246328/dealing-with-bundle-omnibus-list-of-questions-question-that-consists-of-rather-d) of your questions.

Comment: as requested from 2 users i deleted the old question.

Comment: Even the leftover question is barely coherent, sorry.

Comment: what to say..  Capacitors are apparently always a good solution if you want smooth clean voltage .Basicall Many more & always Bigger & higher voltage rated than on most mcu's circuits you find googling. i expectet many more drawbacks. i like capacitors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can use a capacitor to debounce a switch. You just have to make sure that the time constant for the capacitor is larger than the time it takes for the switch to stop bouncing. Basically, you want the switch to finish bouncing before the capacitor gets charged up to the HIGH threshold. Calculating the time constant is complicated because you would need to know the output impedance of whatever power source is charging the capacitor. It could also be affected by other things switching simultaneously in the circuit. It is probably best to figure that out experimentally. If the switch still bounces with a cap across it, add a bigger cap.

Yes you can use multiple capacitors on a power supply. When capacitors are in parallel, the total capacitance is the sum of the individual caps. Having a big capacitance between a power supply and ground makes the voltage more stable (up to the power limits of the supply), at the expense of needing the caps to charge up when the supply is first switched on.

On the importance of the size of a capacitor: In the majority of cases the precise value of the capacitor is not critically important. What is more important is the order of magnitude (uF, mF, nF...). That still doesn't mean you can just pop any capacitor into a circuit and expect it to work. The range of capacitor values you can buy right off the shelf spans 8+ orders of magnitude. You could probably get away with replacing a 10uF cap with a 5uF cap, but you probably can't replace it with a 10nF cap (3 orders of magnitude or 1000 times smaller). It really depends on what the capacitor is used for in the circuit. There are also some circuits where the value of the capacitor *is* is ciritical importance, such as oscillators and precise filters.

Capacitors do have passive energy loss. Every capacitor should specifiy an equivalent series resistance, or ESR. This is a series resistance due to the materials and construction of the capacitor. It's like having a little resistor in series with the capacitor. Any time current flows through the capacitor, a little bit of energy is lost as heat due to this resistance. Capacitors also leak charge. There is a leakage current that slowly discharges capacitors internally. Energy is lost there as well.

Comment: basically if the charging time is not important , multiple sizes&/samesized capacitors wouldn't harm a circuit if smoothness is needed.

Comment: caps don't create any type of interference? what about the ceramic ones (smd)... they create noise ... they oscillate sometimes.

Comment: A capacitor by itself doesn't create any noise (ignoring the thermal noise). Ceramic caps can produce noise because they are sensitive to vibration but these effects are usually small. If you have unwanted oscillations in your circuit it's usually because of feedback or a gain stage that is unstable. Capacitors can actually help to stabilize a gain stage.

Comment: ESR is actually low compared to a linear voltage regulator or a high watt resistor itself... wich concludes to the point that its better to put random sized capacitor btw the vcc&gnd than putting none? so the more capacitors the more stable is the current.

Comment: ESR is usually pretty small but it's important in some high frequency stuff. You probably want a fairy large capacitor between Vcc and Gnd. This will stablize the voltage, not the current.

Comment: sure voltage... it stores current and is able to release it at high speed vs other storing components like batteries. another point for caps.

Comment: To answer your edit: The advantage of adding more capacitance between the Vcc and Gnd will smooth the voltage, filter out voltage ripple and noise from the power supply and switching components. The disadvantage is that large value capacitors are big and expensive and not that reliable. Excessively large capacitors will cause a big surge of current when the circuit is first switched on the charge them up.

Comment: Capacitors are most of the time left appart on those circuits for arduino projects.. your answer cleared most of my doubts. that you need to put them everywehre. thx

Answer (score 2):

What are some drawbacks of adding extra capacitors?

1. Inrush current. This was alluded to in @RobertStiffler's answer. When your power supply first turns on, it will have to provide current to charge up all the capacitors connected to its output. Taken to an extreme, this could result in excess current demand and conceivably even damage the regulator or some other components.
2. Reliability. Electrolytic capacitors, in particular, have limited lifetimes. But lifetime is a statistical thing. With more capacitors, you have more chances to have one part fail early. (On the other hand, you might increase the average lifetime due to reducing the ripple current through any one capacitor. It's a trade-off)

   Ceramic capacitors can also fail, often due to mechanical stress. Again, more capacitors means more possible points of failure.

   More capacitors also gives your assembly shop more chances to screw up, so it could also result in lower out-of-box yield for your product.
3. Cost. More capacitors cost more money. They also take up more board area, making your PCB cost more.

Comment: inrush current is an important point. as i don't know how much current a cap can draw in a short time. lets say the 5v regulator 7805 .. the old one has 1A how many 1000uF 16v capacitors would you need to burn the regulator?

Comment: cost is relative to the products quality. As the answers suggest.. want noisefree circuit... you need more caps... look at those motherboards. There is a cap every 2mm.

Comment: The lifespan of capacitors is irrilevant at the point you realize that everyone changes their phone, pc or other electronic gadget every year. I salvaged most capacitors that i measured, work and use from electronic devices from the 19th century.  they don't last long on commercial devices because they are always at the limit. i replaced caps on 3 old monitors all of them just right after 2 years with slightliy bigger caps they now are still working after 9 years. same happend on my AV Reciever. 5 caps where broken. changed all the array with higher voltage one  and it works until then.

Comment: Is the Inrush current a real problem or only on circuits with really big 1000uF++ cap arrays?

Comment: @cocco, engineering is all about trade-offs. If these issues aren't important in your application, then by all means stuff every square mm of your board with extra bypassing.

Comment: atm i'm trying only to figure out the functionality of those components. leaving aside things like cost how big some of them are  and actually i'm, in a good way, very disappointed that there are no serious drawbacks but that, the more capacitors, the better the circuit is. But srsly .. how many 1000uF 16v caps would it need to burn an 1A 5v 7805 .. is it complex to calculate?

Comment: I mean like i said in the comments i plan to use efficent boost converters from something like one AAA cell. Some of them can't deliver more than 100mA. for sure there is no need for big caps but maybe a 1000uF 6.3v is dangerous to use with only 100mA current

Comment: also apparently the 7805 has a internal current limiting circuit.so the capacitor will not be able to draw more than 1.2A. but some boostconverter don't .. i could not findd anything about to high current rush from capacitors. you prolly need a real big one to get serious problems.

Comment: Yes, you'd need to use a really extreme value to cause a problem. Even then you might be able to work around it by choosing a regulator with a slow-start feature. It might be a show-stopper problem if your device has a very strict turn-on-time requirement.

Comment: turn-on-time requirement ... these days even your watch has a turnontime that takes almost one minute. all "new" electronic devices have a "booting" animation thats somehow bad yeah.. thinking of those old radios,tv's u pressed a button and it worked. no delay no loading screen.

Comment: @cocco, if you just want to shoot the sh*t, please visit [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering). The main site isn't meant for long back-and-forth discussions.

Comment: i think i cleared now most of my questions. thx for your patience

Comment: Whether inrush current will be a problem depends on the size of the caps you are using, but also on the power supply. Some power supplies are able to handle large pulse current or have internal current limiting, as you mentioned.